# Find element by matching attribute key instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With jQuery (or `document.querySelector()`), you can use the following to get elements by its attribute values:

```
//Exact value
$("[attribute='value']");
//Contains value
$("[attribute*='value']");
//Starts with
$("[attribute^='value']");
//Ends with
$("[attribute$='value']");
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is a bit different.

Suppose I have this element:

```
<button ls-click="alert('a')">Click!</button>
```

I need to get that one element because it has an attribute that starts with `ls-`.

jQuery has the [`hasAttribute`](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector that works like `$("[attr]")`, but it only matches elements with that exact attribute, no wildcards accepted.

I could add a class to that button and check every attribute if anything matches with `ls-`, but that is counter intuitive to what I'm trying to achieve.

I could also run trough every DOM element and check if any of them has that attribute (I guess that's what jQuery does anyways), but I think that's not the best solution.

Is there a selector that does that? (If there is some way without jQuery, that'd be interesting to know, too).

Comment: *With jQuery, you can use the following to get elements by its attribute values* Yes. And, without JQuery you can use them as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know about querySelector

Comment: If it works without jQuery, I'll just ditch it as I don't really need it

Comment: `ls-click` is not valid HTML in the first place. Custom attributes should be made with [`data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: I see. I tought of using data, I might use it to keep things alright with html5 conventions. But is it possible to match the data attribute using wildcards?

Comment: why don't you use `data` attribute?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: Using `dataset` will narrow down the list of attributes in browsers that support it, but it'll still be a per-element search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no attribute selector that will select on a partial match of the attribute name.

Best you'll be able to do will be to narrow the list of elements down as much as possible given what other information you know about the element, like a more specific location in the DOM under the `document`, and its tag/class/etc.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("#some_container button");
for (const el of els) {
  for (const attr of el.attributes) {
    if (attr.name.startsWith("ls-")) {
      console.log(attr.value)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do kind of what vue does with its `v-on` directive. I have debugged the source code and vue actually runs trough every element inside the instance's element and checks every attribute on them. In my case, those elements could be anywhere inside the body tag.

Comment: Yeah, then  `document.body.querySelectorAll(...` will help a little. If you know the possible tag name(s), that'll help too. But that's probably as good as you'll get

Comment: I don't think it will be that slow. I've made a fiddle with over 6k elements and it took 31 miliseconds. See: https://jsfiddle.net/rzjctaw7/    be careful as it could crash your browser, it's kinda heavy.

Comment: i think I might just go with that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer "no" to this question horrifies me.

So it made a small script.
I'm not sure that it is totally "fullproof".
But I made it so it wouldn't conflict with other attributes... At least.

Below, all element having an attribute starting with `ls-` get a green background.

```js
var pattern = /ls-.+?=/gm;

var foundAttr = [];
$("body").find("*").not('script').each(function(){
  
  var match = this.outerHTML.toString().match(pattern);
  if(match!=null){
    
    // Remove the = sign
    var attr = match[0].substring(0,match[0].length-1);
    
    // Console the element markup and store it in an array
    foundAttr.push($("["+attr+"]"));
  }
});

// Add a class to each found element
foundAttr.forEach(function(element){
  element.addClass("found");
});
```

```css
.found{
  background-color:green;
}
.something{
  padding:2px;
  margin:0.5em;
  border:1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button ls-click="alert('a')" id="ok">Click!</button>
<h1>ok</h1>
<button ls-hello="alert('a')">Click!</button>
<button class="yo" ls-hello="alert('a')">Click!</button>
<button ls-hello="alert('a')">Click!</button>
<div class="something">
  I'm a div<br>
  <button ls-yes="alert('a')">Click!</button>
</div>

<button no="alert('a')">I'm not found :(</button>
<p>Hello!</p>
<button ls-bye="alert('a')">Click!</button>
```

There is some console.logs in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dJZGVg?editors=1011)

Comment: As I said in my question, I know about this. But it only matches the exact attribute. I need to match elements that have an attribute starting with some term.

Comment: The answer "no" shouldn't horrify you, because it's correct, there is no *selector* that will match on a partial attribute name. I'd think you'd be more concerned about the fragility and performance implications of serializing every body-level element to HTML and performing a regex on each one.

Comment: You have a point... But the starting point of the function could also be a smaller container than `body`... About the performance aspect. That is quite a special case, not knowing the attributes your code has... I tried to address it in just a couple lines and it worked. I think i can be usefull to some (very few) people.